How to retrieve all the Public Email Templates where FolderName is 'Public Email Templates'
I have tried using the following query :
SELECT Id, Name, Subject, Folder.Name FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Folder.Name = 'Public Email Templates' 
But it doesn't works.
one can query an email template and see that the Folder.Name Indeed Shows up to be Public Email Templates however  the Folder.DeveloperName comes as blank
The point being I am not able to target the public email templates on the basis of FolderName or Folder.Name fields via SOQL
How is this question different from the other similar question ?
In that question the solution was to use Folder.Name , here I've tried using that and every possible permutation of the word Folder and Name
This question was posted after reading the solution to the similarly being recommended question

This question is similar to: Select by Folder Name for Email Template in SOQL. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Querying by Folder.Name does work as shown in the linked question; if you are seeing a different behavior, could you add screenshots that illustrate the issue?  For example, a screenshot of Developer Console showing a query of an email template that displays Folder.Name as 'Public Email Templates', and one showing the complete failing query.

The 'Public' folder is actually just the Org Id.
(just like the 'My private' folder is the running user's id)
ie.
String orgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();

List<EmailTemplate> emailTemplates = [SELECT Name FROM EmailTemplate WHERE FolderId = :orgId];

The label 'Public Email Templates' is just a label Salesforce provide in the UI.  It's not in the database and therefore can't be queried for.
If you just want just lightning email templates, add AND UiType = 'SFX' to the query.
ie.
String orgId = UserInfo.getOrganizationId();

List<EmailTemplate> emailTemplates = [SELECT Name FROM EmailTemplate WHERE FolderId = :orgId AND UiType = 'SFX'];

